# Trying to shorten a route by using "routes.MapRoute" but I get the error “The resource cannot be found.”

Tags: asp.net-mvc, resources, asp.net-mvc-routing

Right now I’m using the following route:

```
http://localhost/Ancora/MiniSites/Index/Lilly
```

I’m trying to shortening to:

```
http://LocalHost/Ancora/Lilly
```

By using the next code in Global.asax.cs:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "MiniSite",
        "{code}",
        new { controller = "MiniSites", action = "Index", code = "" },
    );
}
```

But I get the Error:

“The resource cannot be found.”

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

If this //localhost/Ancora/MiniSites/Index/Lilly is working  then it must be calling the action method MiniSites in the controller Ancora and passing it Index and Lilly as parameters. If you want //LocalHost/Ancora/Lilly to map to the first URL try the following code:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "MiniSite",
    "{controler}/{param2}",
    new { controller = "Ancora", action = "MiniSites", param1 = "Index", param2 = "Lilly" }
);
```

where param1 and param2 are the names of the parameters to the action method MiniSites in the Ancora Controller.